# Undefined control sequence \draw and \end{tikzpicture}

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a picture in LaTex. When I compile the file it gives me an undefined control sequence error. I tried to compare it with my other documents but I can't find where the error is.
I am attaching here my file. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,mindmap,trees,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{sverb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}


\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\scriptsize$\blacksquare$} 

\usepackage{pgffor,pgf}
\newcommand{\MOD}[2]{\pgfmathparse{int(mod(#1,#2))}\pgfmathresult }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, line width=1]

\definecolor{rojo}{rgb}{0.81,0.10,0}
\definecolor{rojo_1}{rgb}{0.81,0.30,0}
\definecolor{rojo_2}{rgb}{0.81,0.60,0}
\definecolor{verde}{rgb}{0.12, 0.35, 0.14}
\definecolor{verde_1}{rgb}{0.22, 0.60, 0.15}
\definecolor{verde_2}{rgb}{0.30, 0.80, 0.20}
\definecolor{azul}{rgb}{0, 0.30, 0.80}
\definecolor{azul_1}{rgb}{0, 0.10, 0.60}
\definecolor{azul_2}{rgb}{0, 0.10, 0.90}
\definecolor{morado}{rgb}{0.7, 0.20, 0.50}

\draw 

    (-11,4) node (1) [label=above:$\mathsf{G_{1}}$] {$\bullet$}
    (-11,3) node (2)  [] {$\bullet$}
    (-11,2) node (3)[] {$\bullet$}
    (-11,1) node (4) [] {$\bullet$)
    (-11,-1) node (5) [] {$\bullet$}
    (-11,-2) node (6)  [] {$\bullet$}
    (-11,-3) node (7)[] {$\bullet$}
    (-11,-4) node (8) [] {$\bullet$)

    (-9,4) node (9) [label=above:$\mathsf{G_{2}}$] {$\bullet$}
    (-9,3) node (10)  [] {$\bullet$}
    (-9,2) node (11)[] {$\bullet$}
    (-9,1) node (12) [] {$\bullet$)
    (-9,-1) node (13) [] {$\bullet$}
    (-9,-2) node (14)  [] {$\bullet$}
    (-9,-3) node (15)[] {$\bullet$}
    (-9,-4) node (16) [] {$\bullet$)

    (-7,4) node (17) [label=above:$\mathsf{G_{3}}$] {$\bullet$}
    (-7,3) node (18)  [] {$\bullet$}
    (-7,2) node (19)[] {$\bullet$}
    (-7,1) node (20) [] {$\bullet$)
    (-7,-1) node (21) [] {$\bullet$}
    (-7,-2) node (22)  [] {$\bullet$}
    (-7,-3) node (23)[] {$\bullet$}
    (-7,-4) node (24) [] {$\bullet$)

    (-5,4) node (25) [label=above:$\mathsf{G_{3}}$] {$\bullet$}
    (-5,3) node (26)  [] {$\bullet$}
    (-5,2) node (27)[] {$\bullet$}
    (-5,1) node (28) [] {$\bullet$)
    (-5,-1) node (29) [] {$\bullet$}
    (-5,-2) node (30)  [] {$\bullet$}
    (-5,-3) node (31)[] {$\bullet$}
    (-5,-4) node (32) [] {$\bullet$)

    (-8,-6) node (33) [label=below:$\mathsf{\infty}$] {$\bullet$}

;

\draw 

(9)edge[postaction={decorate}, rojo](17)
(17)edge[postaction={decorate}, rojo](29)
(13)edge[postaction={decorate}, rojo](21)
(21)edge[postaction={decorate}, rojo](25)
(2)edge[postaction={decorate}, rojo](22)
(22)edge[postaction={decorate}, rojo](30)
(6)edge[postaction={decorate}, rojo](18)
(18)edge[postaction={decorate}, rojo](26)
(3)edge[postaction={decorate}, rojo](11)
(11)edge[out=45,in=135, postaction={decorate}, rojo](27)
(7)edge[postaction={decorate}, rojo](15)
(15)edge[out=-45,in=-135, postaction={decorate}, rojo](31)
(4)edge[postaction={decorate}, rojo](16)
(16)edge[postaction={decorate}, rojo](20)
(8)edge[postaction={decorate}, rojo](12)
(12)edge[postaction={decorate}, rojo](24)

;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

One of your copy/pastes has this line

```
(-5,1) node (28) [] {$\bullet$)
```

so it opens the braces and the rest is usual TeX behavior; complain about the most distant and irrelevant thing encountered in the code. I sometimes think that TeX reads twice to find the most obscure error message.

Also please check your package declarations, you practically load `graphicx` five times, `pgf` three times.

TikZ loads `pgf` and all `pgf*` modules and also loads `graphicx`.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't see the error until now. I had done the same thing repeatedly. It works now. And I eliminated some of the packages. I am new at LaTex, and it gives me troubles quite often.

Comment: TikZ loads graphicx? I never knew that! Thanks.